# how to pass data from json to a php function?

Tags: php, json, post

```
[registration] => Array
    (
        [first_name] => test
        [location] => Array
            (
                [name] => Santa Ana
                [id] => 1.08081209215E+14
            )
        [gender] => female
        [password] => 123654789
    )
```

and i need to insert that data into a database by using:

```
$carray = fns_create_talent($login, $pass, $gender, $name);
```

any idea on how to get them from a place to another?

i was thinking that i need to assign the array values to the post vars. maybe:

```
$login = registration.first_name...
```

any ideas?
thanks

Comment: what you have there is not JSON: http://json.org/

Comment: good point, it's just an array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$login = $json['registration']['first_name']
```

Comment: `$json` should be the variable with the value you gave us.

Answer (score 3):

What you have shown is not JSON, but PHP's array. I am assuming this is the structure of the data you want to be sent to the server.

You can do it like that (remember, there are no associative arrays in JavaScript!):

- on Javascript side do something similar to this:

  ```
  var data = {
      'registration': {
          'first_name': 'test',
          'location': {
              'name': 'Santa Ana',
              'id': '1.08081209215E+14'
          },
          'gender': 'female',
          'password': 123654789
      }
  }
  ```
- and then use `data` in eg. [jQuery .post()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) as the second parameter.
- on the PHP side just read from `$_POST` as you read multi-dimensional associative arrays. In this case it should look similar to:

  ```
  // I have made assumption here (you do not have
  // 'login' variable in your example)
  $login = $_POST['registration']['first_name'];

  $pass = $_POST['registration']['password'];
  $gender = $_POST['registration']['gender'];
  $name = $_POST['registration']['first_name'];
  $carray = fns_create_talent($login, $pass, $gender, $name);
  ```

Here you go.

Comment: -1 `array('key' => 'value')` __is__ an associative array. Also, you contradict yourself by saying there are multi-dimensional arrays, after strongly suggesting that there is no such thing.

Comment: @Gabi yes, it was a typo: I meant 'there are no associative arrays in JavaScript', which is true and next I am showing the JSON object the OP may be referring to - for some people it may be obvious to assume I was saying about JavaScript. Would you be so kind now and remove your downvote?

Answer (score 0):

EDITED:

Where $arr is the array you submitted.

```
$carray = fns_create_talent( 
    /* your login var */,
    $arr['registration']['password'],
    $arr['registration']['gender'],
    $arr['registration']['first_name']
);
```

I don't see your login inside the array, so I just put a comment for the login var, but you should get the idea.

Comment: my bad, it was not json, i got confused, it's just an array, but the question still applys

Comment: Edited to not be json, but just handle the array